# Get index of checked ChekBox in listview windows store app c#

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, windows-store-apps

I am developing one windows store application. There is one listview and listview contains Image , Checkbox Controls.
XAML Code:

```
<ListView Name="display" ItemsSource="{Binding}"   SelectionMode="Single" 
 SelectionChanged="display_SelectionChanged" 
 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   
 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle12}" >
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel x:Name="stak2" Orientation="Horizontal" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image Source="{Binding  Path=Image}" Width="450" Tapped="image_taped" />
            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Path=tag}" Visibility="{Binding Path=visichk}" Height="40"      Name="addremove" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="add_checked" Unchecked="sub_checked"  Opacity="0.5" 
                 Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Template="{StaticResource CheckboxImageTemplate}" >
            </CheckBox>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Image_code}" FontSize="25" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

I want to get  index(Position) of checked CheckBox in add_checked event of checkbox.
how can it possible please help me.

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple Property that binds to the IsChecked property of the CheckBox, and whenever needed, simply use a simple LINQ to get all the checked items?

Comment: What is LINQ FOR LISTVIEW.
i want to get the data  of listview item  where checkbox is checked. how can it possible. see my another quetion please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26054912/get-checked-items-of-listview-using-checkbox-windows-store-app-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, that's what you will get then. Just add a property in the class whos collection you are binding to itemssource.

Comment: thnks ok i will  try. please help me for my another question which i have linked to this question.